# addEventListener not working with keys

Tags: javascript

key events appear to only work with mouse keys not keyboard keys.
I get the popup on a mouse click but not on any keyboard input

HTML
    
    
    
    
    Untitled Document

Javscript file:

```
window.addEventListener('keypress', redrawAvatar(event), true);
window.addEventListener('keydown', redrawAvatar(event), true);
window.addEventListener('keyup', redrawAvatar(event), true);

function redrawAvatar(e)
{
    alert("hello world");

}
```

Comment: HTML is missing from my post. HTML just has the reference to the javascript file and nothing else

Comment: When calling a handler, use the name of the function and not the return value, ie `redrawAvatar` instead of `redrawAvatar(event)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be:

```
window.addEventListener('keypress', redrawAvatar, true);
```

(The second argument is the function itself, not the result of a call to it.)